# How to get the PID of matlab when using the MATLAB Engine?

Tags: matlab, unix, pid, matlab-engine

When using the [MATLAB Engine interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html), how can I get the process ID of the matlab process that is started?  Or how can I launch the matlab process in a way that would allow me to also get the PID?

The reason why I need this is to be able to interrupt calculations when they take too long.  On *nix systems this seems to work by sending a SIGINT signal to MATLAB.  This won't kill MATLAB, but it will interrupt the current calculation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evaluate the following in MATLAB to get the PID:

```
feature('GetPid')
```

I found this [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function/).